# Spring Boot: @GetMapping with Pageable as request parameter don't work as expected

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using **Spring Boot 2** and I have write a `@RestController` within a `@GetMapping` that takes a `Pageable` as parameter.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<AppointmentTO>> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<AppointmentTO> page = appointmentService.findAll(pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(page);
}
```

The problem is the following:

By each request, the **queries-parameters** `pageSize` and `offset` are always reset to default when they arrived in Spring Boot Backend (`?offset=0&pageSize=20`), however I send different parameters in the url of my request (`?offset=15&pageSize=5` for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Boot maps the request params to `org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest` that extends `AbstractPageRequest`

```
  AbstractPageRequest implements Pageable, Serializable {
    ...
    private final int page;
    private final int size;

    public long getOffset() {
        return (long)this.page * (long)this.size;
    }
    ...
```

You should use following url:

```
http://localhost:8080?page=3&size=5
```

Also you could add sorting by ...&sort=name

Comment: Or customize the param names: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/config/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot `Pageable` supports the following url params OOTB:

- page: page number, where 0 is the first page
- size: page size
- sort: sort by field
- direction: ASC/DESC

**Sample endpoint:**

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userService.getUsers(pageable));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Sample Request:**

```
localhost:8080/users?page=2&size=5&sort=createdAt,DESC
```

**Sample Response** (note the paging data below):

```
{
    "content": [
       ... 
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": false,
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false
        },
        "offset": 10,
        "pageNumber": 2,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 12,
    "totalElements": 58,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 2,
    "sort": {
        "empty": false,
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false
    },
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "first": false,
    "empty": false
}
```